# Acrobat PDF viewer control takes time to dispose

Tags: vb.net, winforms, axacropdf

This issue affects both my VB.NET and C# `Winform` applications. When closing `Form` containing `Adobe PDF Viewer` conreol, the `Form` takex some 10 seconds to close. I tracked the issue down to `Dispose` method. Normally, in C# all it takes it so steal focus from `Adobe PDF Control` by adding lines to `FormClosing` event handler but in VB.NET, even if I steal focus, it still takes way too long for the `Form` to close. I tried to explicitly dispose the control and Implicitly - by disposing the containing `Form`. I tried empty string in `LoadFile()` method. I tried new reference to new interop library. Nothing works. 
 Also, if you would suggest a different API/library to replace `AxAcroPDFlib` I'd love to read what you use.

Comment: Have the same problem (c#. net). Fast fix is to us older version ( https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/install-reader-x-windows.html ). If you find out something pleas update this post.

Comment: Moving focus to a different control on the closing event was working in our VB.NET app until a few days ago. We received an update to Adobe and are seeing the delay again. Haven't found a solution yet. I'm going to be moving to a different control at some point but hoping to find a workaround for this for now.

Answer (score 1):

I now have a solution. Early testing is promising.
In short, add `Controls.Remove(yourPdfViewerControl)` to `FormClosing` event handler. Of course this will offer instant alleviation of the problem but may cause memory leak. After you have removed the control from `Container` you could assugn `null` to its memory address and hope that memory manager will do its job. 
 So in order to prevent the leak, I created a class holding one memory space for `PdfViewer` control. If a `Form` needs a viewer, it requests it from an object that is accessible from any form to prevent memory leaks. To avoid `Dispose` method invocation when `Form` closes, make sure you remove this `Control` from `Controls` container.
I can provide sample code if needed.